# Calculate the series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

There is given series

- $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n(n+r))^{a}}$

Where $r$ is natural number, and $a$ is a reral number big enough so that this series is convergent.

> Calculate the value of this series in terms of $a$ and $r$

I tried to corelate this with some values of zeta function or multiple zeta function but i failed.

I hope for your help.

Regards.

Comment: No hope for closed form, if exist.Equivalent to integrals:$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(n (n+r))^a}=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} (r x)} \sqrt{\pi } r^{\frac{1}{2}-a}
   x^{-\frac{1}{2}+a} I_{-\frac{1}{2}+a}\left(\frac{r x}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (a) (\exp (x)-1)} \, dx=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-r x}
   x^{-1+a} \text{Li}_a\left(e^{-x}\right)}{\Gamma (a)} \, dx$ where: $I_{a-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{r x}{2}\right)$ and $\text{Li}_a\left(e^{-x}\right)$ is:modified Bessel function of the first kind and polylogarithm function.